# get multiple address from multiple latitude/longitude

Tags: android, google-maps, google-geocoder

I want to get addresses of multiple latitude/longitude, is there any way to do that in one request?

I can get address of one location using this code :

```
try {
 Geocoder geocoder;
 List<Address> addresses;
 geocoder = new Geocoder(MainActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());
 addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(Double.parseDouble(latitude), Double.parseDouble(longitude), 1);
 String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
 Log.i("adresse :", address);
 } catch (IOException e) {
     Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
    }
```

any help please.

Answer (score 1):

Make a method, pass it your list of coordinates LatLngs and loop through the code you already have.

Comment: my question is : I want to use the service of google (getlocationfrom) one time, to get data for multiple coordinates, is there any way to send list of coordinate and get results in one time

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that the API does not support multiple locations per request.

The long answer is that Google has designed the Geocoder API such that the clients will not exhaust the request limit if you do client-side Geocoding.  See the [following quote from this FAQ:](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geocodestrat)

> **When to Use Client-Side Geocoding**
>
> The basic answer is "almost always." As geocoding limits are per user
>   session, there is no risk that your application will reach a global
>   limit as your userbase grows. Client-side geocoding will not face a
>   quota limit unless you perform a batch of geocoding requests within a
>   user session. Therefore, running client-side geocoding, you generally
>   don't have to worry about your quota.
>
> Two basic architectures for client-side geocoding exist.
>
> Run the geocoding and display entirely in the browser. For instance,
>   the user enters an address on your page. Your application geocodes it.
>   Then your page uses the geocode to create a marker on the map. Or your
>   app does some simple analysis using the geocode. No data is sent to
>   your server. This reduces load on your server, but doesn't give you
>   any sense of what your users are doing.
>
> Run the geocode in the browser and then send it to the server. For
>   instance, the user enters an address. Your application geocodes it in
>   the browser. The app then sends the data to your server. The server
>   responds with some data, such as nearby points of interest. This
>   allows you to customize a response based on your own data, and also to
>   cache the geocode if you want. This cache allows you to optimize even
>   more. You can even query the server with the address, see if you have
>   a recently cached geocode for it, and if you do, use that. If you
>   don't, then return no result to the browser, and let it geocode the
>   result and send it back to the server to for caching.

For more specifics on limits on Geocoding requests, [see this URL](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#geocoder_limit).

Comment: so please what is the solution, because I have many coordinates how can I get the addresses fastly